# How to fix Java error Unsupported major.minor version 52.0 when using Apache Jena tdbloader

Tags: java, jena, tdb, tdbloader

On a Apache Jena 3.1.0 on Ubuntu 14.04, while trying to use tdbloader to load triples to a triple store, I've got the following error:

> tdb/tdbloader : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0

Any hints appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This errors is normally related to mismatching versions of Java on compiled software and on the user system.

Check you java version:

```
java -version
```

If your java version is 1.7, upgrade it to 1.8:

```
 sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
 sudo apt-get update
 sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
```

After this, all your jena programs should run fine.